# move image inside imageview getting bounderies

Tags: android-studio

i am working on a app and in 1 option i can load a photo to display when you scroll through items.
The permissions and loading all works fine. 
Now my photo is bigger than the imageview so i want that the user can "move" the photo to display the section he/she wants to show.
Again implementing the onTouchListerner and scrolling the photo works fine.
The problem is where to stop the moving of the photo.

[image: example picture]

I the picture above the grey part is my photo. In my case 2560x1920.
The red part is my imageview (match_parent x 85dp => 1368x255)
I have my scaletype set to CENTER_CROP resulting in a scalefactor of 0.534375

when i scroll in the image ( scrollBy(x,y) ) i can see my Y moves between -390..390 (or close by, hard to see). But that is of course only the case for this specific photo. But no matter which adding/substracting/dividing/... is do i can not seem to find out how the get this limit becuause what is absolutly do not want is the right situation in the picture above.

Does anybody have an idea to figure this out.
I found some (not a lot) examples that are suppose to work but they do not.
Mostly they work by keeping to total somewhere but still having a total is not of much use if you do not no the min/max.

ps. if possible at all (please please) a java example and not kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this post by Elye: [Android View Scrolling Made Simple](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/android-view-scrolling-made-simple-2bae4209eca1) 
Now this did not work "out of the box" for me but it did give me the hint i needed to make it work. The magic for me was in this code past the determines the bouderies:

```
    val bounds = RectF()
    imageMatrix.mapRect(bounds, RectF(drawable.bounds))
    leftLimit   = if (bounds.left < 0) bounds.left else 0f
    topLimit    = if (bounds.top < 0) bounds.top else 0f
    rightLimit  = (if (bounds.right > width) bounds.right else width.toFloat()) - width
    bottomLimit = (if (bounds.bottom > height) bounds.bottom else height.toFloat()) - height
```